# javascript combobox text style in ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, combobox

I am developping a basic application in javascript using jquery. i put my app a combobox like below. my problem is that this code work in ie9 perfect. in ie8 or ie7 items in combobox loaded my combobox but text doesnt seem. what could be the solution. any idea?
(note: Problem is occurs in asp.net pages and this problem is for only option text colors which i create dynamically)

```
$cmbIller = $('<select id=\'cmbIller\' />');
$cmbIller.css({ 'list-style': 'none', 'background': '#cf5a5a', 'position': 'absolute', 'top': '10px', 'left': comboboxesLeft, 'width': comboboxesWidth, 'padding': '2px', color: "#696969" });

$cmbIller.change(function () { cmbIllerSelectedChanged(); });

containerDiv.append($cmbIller);

$('#cmbIller').append(new Option("Seçiniz", -1));
```

best regards